# python: how to change shape of the output of skimage resize

Tags: python, scikit-image

I'm using `skimage.transform.resize`. Suppose a figure is `180x180`-pixel, with 3 channels.

For example:

```
from skimage.transform import resize
x = resize(im, (16, 16))
```

The shape of the result, i.e. `x` is `(16x16x3)`. That is, the third dimension of `x` indicates the channel. However, I hope to get a result with shape `(3x16x16)`. That is, I need the first dimension of the array to indicate the channel. How can I achieve this?

Thank you all for helping me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a job for numpy's [rollaxis](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.rollaxis.html), numpy being also the core of scikit-image.

**Edit:** or maybe more intuitive: [np.moveaxis](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.moveaxis.html#numpy.moveaxis).

Code:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(48).reshape((4, 4, 3))
print(a)
print(a.shape)

b = np.rollaxis(a, 2)  # complete roll as 3rd argument void -> start=0
# or: b = np.moveaxis(a, 2, 0)
print(b)
print(b.shape)

print(a[2,3,0])
print(b[0,2,3])
```

Output:

```
[[[ 0  1  2]
  [ 3  4  5]
  [ 6  7  8]
  [ 9 10 11]]

 [[12 13 14]
  [15 16 17]
  [18 19 20]
  [21 22 23]]

 [[24 25 26]
  [27 28 29]
  [30 31 32]
  [33 34 35]]

 [[36 37 38]
  [39 40 41]
  [42 43 44]
  [45 46 47]]]
(4, 4, 3)
[[[ 0  3  6  9]
  [12 15 18 21]
  [24 27 30 33]
  [36 39 42 45]]

 [[ 1  4  7 10]
  [13 16 19 22]
  [25 28 31 34]
  [37 40 43 46]]

 [[ 2  5  8 11]
  [14 17 20 23]
  [26 29 32 35]
  [38 41 44 47]]]
(3, 4, 4)
33
33
```